# How to fix chapter heading appearing before new chapter?

Tags: titlesec

I've set up a title page for each chapter, but I can't figure out why the chapter heading is appearing before the chapter.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{\chaptername\ \thechapter\ --\ \leftmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

\mainmatter
    
\titleclass{\chapter}{page}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
\titleformat{\chapter}
    [display]
    {\centering\Huge\bfseries}
    {\chaptertitlename{}\ \thechapter}
    {0pt}
    {\huge}
    [\clearpage]

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\input{chapters/chapter1}
\input{chapters/chapter2}
\input{chapters/chapter3}
\input{chapters/chapter4}
\input{chapters/chapter5}
\input{chapters/chapter6}

\end{document}
```

[image: end of chapter 3]
[image: start of chapter 4]

Answer (score 1):

This code used the `explicit` parameter of `titlesec` so that it could use the format setting for `\chapter` to set the left mark when using the chapter title.

The command `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{...` formats the left mark with the dash.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}% changed <<<<
    
\titleclass{\chapter}{page}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
\titleformat{\chapter}
[display]
{\centering\Huge\bfseries}
{\chaptertitlename{}\ \thechapter}
{0pt}
{\huge}
[#1\markboth{#1}{}\clearpage]% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<
    
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase\leftmark}% changed <<<<<<<<<<
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
    
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{% format the left mark <<<<
    \markboth{\normalfont\sffamily\chaptername\ \thechapter\ --  #1}{}}

    \usepackage{kantlipsum}% only dummy text
\begin{document}

    \mainmatter% in here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \chapter{The First}
    \kant[1-4]
    \chapter{The Second}
    \kant[1-4]
    \chapter{Behavior, HPA Axis and Hormones}
    \kant[1-4]
    \chapter{GABA\textsubscript{A} Receptor Subunit Expression}
        \section{Introduction}
    \kant[1-4]
        
\end{document}
```